# How to find which of the given components satisfy the existence of a certain bijectivity on GAP

Tags: semigroups, gap, programming

I'm trying solve the following problem:

Let  $Q$  be a given set and $G$ the monoid generated by $x,y,z$ nonnegative integers.
How to find which of the given components of $Q$ satisfies the condition such that mapping
$(p,q,r) -> (x^py^qz^r)$, from $Q$ to $G$  is bijection.

My attempt:

```
F := FreeMonoid("x", "y", "z");

generators := GeneratorsOfMonoid(F);;

G := F/relations;

generators := GeneratorsOfMonoid(G);;

Q:=[ [ 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1 ], [ 0, 0, 2 ], [ 0, 0, 3 ], [ 0, 0, 4 ], [ 0, 0, 5 ], [ 0, 0, 6 ],
  [ 0, 0, 7 ], [ 0, 0, 8 ], [ 0, 0, 9 ], [ 0, 0, 10 ], [ 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 1, 1 ], [ 0, 1, 2 ],
  [ 0, 1, 3 ], [ 0, 1, 4 ], [ 0, 1, 5 ], [ 0, 1, 6 ], [ 0, 1, 7 ], [ 0, 1, 8 ], [ 0, 1, 9 ],
  [ 0, 1, 10 ], [ 0, 2, 0 ], [ 0, 2, 1 ], [ 0, 2, 2 ], [ 0, 2, 3 ], [ 0, 2, 4 ], [ 0, 2, 5 ],
  [ 0, 2, 6 ], [ 0, 2, 7 ], [ 0, 2, 8 ], [ 0, 2, 9 ], [ 0, 2, 10 ], [ 0, 3, 0 ], [ 0, 3, 1 ],
  [ 0, 3, 2 ], [ 0, 3, 3 ], [ 0, 3, 4 ], [ 0, 3, 5 ]];

Filtered(Q, Q -> x^p*y^q*z^r IsBijection);
Syntax error: ) expected in *errin*:1
Filtered(Q, Q -> x^p*y^q*z^r IsBijection);
```

Thanx, in advance

Comment: You need to use `IsBijection` as a function.

Comment: Thanx a lot dear professor, but can you advise me how to do it please. I need to select which components of $Q$ satisfy the condition

Comment: @BenaHajdari could you please use formatting for code in your questions? For example see the edit I have just made to format code blocks with three backticks before and after it. Or, if you have a short fragment of code, put it in single backticks, so it will look `like this`.